# turtlebot 3d print

Tags: turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does anyone know of open HW 3d print files for turtlebot platform?  Hope this question is ok to ask here.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226475/turtlebot-3d-print/) by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 713 on 2016-02-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Found stl files under
https://github.com/TurtleBot-Mfg/turtlebot-doc-dev/find/master
don't know if they are good for printing

---

Originally posted by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) with karma: 713 on 2016-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2016-03-03**:
The parts are typically laser cut or water jetted due to their size instead of 3D printed.